# cgminer settings "--load-balance" vs "--balance"?

Tags: cgminer

http://www.amilitalia.it/github.com/ckolivas/cgminer.html

I'm looking for the best balance:

```
--load-balance Change multipool strategy from failover to quota based balance
```

and

```
--balance Change multipool strategy from failover to even share balance
```

How exactly it works?

E.g. there are 2 pool for different alt-coins with scrypt algo.

- 1st pool: difficulty 1.1234
- 2nd pool: difficulty 10.123

Is `--balance` set my cgminer to 90% for the second pool? Say, it will waiting for balance of `ACCEPTED` shares.

And `--load-balance` set power of cgminer to 50%/50%?

---

I'm afraid that one pool might go slow, will not give jobs. Will cgminer wait for this pool with `--balance` to keep balance of shares?

---

Peoples, I know that this is very old, overgrown with moss topic. Could somebody provide me with true link to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

From: https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/master/cgminer.c

```
/* In balanced mode, the amount of diff1 solutions per pool is monitored as a
 * rolling average per 10 minutes and if pools start getting more, it biases
 * away from them to distribute work evenly. The share count is reset to the
 * rolling average every 10 minutes to not send all work to one pool after it
 * has been disabled/out for an extended period. */
```

So `--balance` looks to the diff1 count and tries to get an even distribution.

`--load-balance` looks at the `--quota` values and distributes work in proportion to the GCD of them, counting down until remaining quotas are all 0 and the values are reset.